# Removing the margin on a picture in html/css

Tags: html, css, margin, replit

[What the page currently looks like and the margin I want to remove](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VW0HS.png)

I want to remove the white border around the image. I tried a lot of things nothing seems to be working.
Here's what I have so far. HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>repl.it</title>
    <link href="home.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body style="background-color:white;">
    <img src="Banner1.jpg" width=100% height=200px>
  <div >
       <center> <a href="about.html"> About </a> 
        <a href="MyFeed.html">My Feed</a></center>
    <script src="home.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And in CSS

```
.col{ float: left;
        background-color: #0f83c775;
        height:3px;
        width:33%;
        position:"fixed";
         overflow:auto;}
.body{max-width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
            padding:0;
}
.img{max-width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
            padding:0;
                margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;

}
```

Comment: `body {`, not `.body {`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you only putted a . before img and body that makes you define, instead of the img and body elements, the img and body classes.

this is your corrected css:

```
.col{ float: left;
        background-color: #0f83c775;
        height:3px;
        width:33%;
        position:"fixed";
         overflow:auto;}
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
}
img{
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
}
```

Instead of max-width use only width and don't put a width attribute to the body the

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

that you have in the head will make the body take the width of the screen

But i don't understand what do you want to define with .col, if it is the link to myfeed.html instead of .col{ you should put a{

Hope it will help

Comment: Thank you very much! This was really helpful.